# Async queue polling and Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We are building a microservices platform that will accept REST API traffic and processes messages from an internal async queue for inter-container communication.

We are using the built in dependency injection for controllers and that works well, but I am wondering how to manage dependency injection for async queues.

Here is what I have right now:

On Startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    new QueueSubscriber().SubScribe<MessageHandler>();
}
```

The subscriber

```
public void Subscribe<T>()
{
    Task.Run(() => Poll<T>());
}

private async Task Poll<T>()
{
    // Polling logic here

    // Found message
    Task.Run(() => CallHandler<T>()
}

public async Task CallHandler<T>()
{
    // I want to inject dependencies here
    var handler = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as IMessageHandler<T>;
    await handler.HandleMessage();
}
```

I can't find anything on being able to use the available dependency injection that is provided by using `services.AddSingleton<IDependency, Dependency>();`

I see the implementing the IHostedServices pattern but that won't allow me to inject dependencies into the new instances of message handlers

EDIT: Here is what I have for now, creating a instance of the message handler and passing that through, not sure if this is the best way though.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IDependency dependency)
{
    new QueueSubscriber().SubScribe(new MessageHandler(dependency);
}
```

The subscriber

```
public void Subscribe<T>(IMessageHandler<T> handler)
{
    Task.Run(() => Poll(handler));
}

private async Task Poll<T>(IMessageHandler<T> handler)
{
    // Polling logic here in while loop

    // Found message
    Task.Run(() => CallHandler(handler)
}

public async Task CallHandler<T>(IMessageHandler<T> handler)
{
    await handler.HandleMessage();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you're having difficulty with. Why aren't you using the hosted service?

Comment: Edited for more clarification, the hosted service will allow me to inject into the polling logic, but I would want the polling logic to create a new instance of a message handler with dependencies injected